# How to properly upload a 200MB file to GitHub using LFS

Tags: git, neo4j, git-lfs

I have spent many hours so far trying to upload a Neo4j database to GitHub from the command line using LFS. After creating the local repository with `git init` and commiting for the first time, I'm having troubles in the push.

If I am not mistaken, there is only one file with size over 100MB, one of the database core files. Therefore, since there is only one huge file, I used the command `git lfs track "/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.transaction.db.0"` (with and without the initial `/` in the path). I have also tried `git lfs track "*.db"`, `git lfs track "/data/databases/graph.db/*"` and manual editions of .gitattributes, but none of these methods worked. The error is the following:

[image: CMD error]

LFS seems to be not uploading that file in spite of the instructions to do so. My LFS version is 2.7.2, so this is not about an outdated version. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you may have updated your `master` branch to track the large file in Git LFS as of the latest revision, there is likely still history that contains the large file as a plain Git object. GitHub will not let you upload any blob larger than 100 MB anywhere in your history.

In order to fix this, you'll need to rewrite the history. You can use `git lfs migrate import` to do that, like so:

```
git lfs migrate import --everything --include="*.db.0"
```

That will rewrite the history of your entire project, including all branches and tags, so that in all revisions that file is a Git LFS file. You can see the configuration options you can use in [the manual page](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/man/git-lfs-migrate.1.ronn).

As a note, Git, even with Git LFS, is generally not a good tool to handle compiled, built assets like databases. The general recommendation is that if database contents are required (say, for tests), that a source format for the database is included in the repository and the database itself is built as a build or test step if that's necessary. Doing so may or may not make your file small enough that Git LFS is not needed.

Comment: Although I had to solve some additional issues, it eventually worked. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks a lot :)